# BackUp is Failing when there's obstacle at Front of the Robot

Tags: ros2, nav2

I am using ROS2 Humble in my robot, In Nav2 i am using BackUp Node as my recovery behavior, whenever FollowPath is failing i used to take BackUp, but BackUp is only succeeding whenever there's no obstacle on front and back (both). But BackUp is only need to check on the Behind of the robot, but it is checking Front side also, The reason may be backup also using the Same DriveOnHeading so it is checking obstacle on front side also.

```
[behavior_server]: Running backup
[behavior_server]: Collision Ahead - Exiting DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server]: backup failed
[behavior_server]: [backup] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
```